# Custom report generation

Tags: apex, reporting

I need to generate a report using a particular set of information. In my code we I have a webservice call out service which returns a JSON. I need to generate reports with this JSON information. Is it possible to generate report without saving date into database? Is it possible to generate report from apex class? Please guide me.

Comment: You could potentially use a VF page display the json in a format you want to. I dont think you can use salesforce report on data which is not in the database

Answer (score 1):

Few things:

1. You will have to save JSON date into some custom/standard object in Salesforce to leverage the standard report. Once data is in database standard reports can be generated. You can parse Json data using [this way](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_json_jsonparser.htm).
2. If you don't want to save data in Salesforce, you will have to parse json on the fly and then show those values in visualforce page. So, it will require visualforce page. It can have various other complexities depending on json. In this case also you will have to [parse json](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_json_jsonparser.htm).